# Casting a list as QVariant or QVariant List

Tags: qt, qvariant

My problem is this. I have lists of different numeric types, for example:

```
QList<qreal> mylist;
```

Now, in my code I have a function that that expects a QVariant argument which is mylist. The only way I've found to do this is by using a for cyle and simply adding all of the data in mylist to second list

```
QList<QVariant> temp,
```

for example, and passing temp as a paramter.

I was wondering if there was any other way to do this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've had to do this several times, and to my knowledge the only way is to create a new list.

If this is something you have to do frequently with varying types of lists you could do something a little fancier:

```
template <typename T>
QVariantList toVariantList( const QList<T> &list )
{
    QVariantList newList;
    foreach( const T &item, list )
        newList << item;

    return newList;
}
```

so that when you call your function that takes in the QVariant list, you can just call

```
myFunction( toVariantList(myList) );
```

Note that the given function will only work for types that can be implicitly converted to QVariants.

Comment: It's what I've feared. Thank you!

Comment: Note QVariant itself is already able to convert from `QList<T>` to `QVariantList`. This means you could also use QVariant to perform the conversion.