# How can i save a QList of a own class using QSettings in QT?

Tags: qt

My project is to simulate a "create newtorks" application like PacketTracer and i want to be able to save the status of the project, so after closing and re-running the app, everything is still there if the user wants to. I have used QSetting where I have a SaveSettings() and a LoadSettings() called from button's clicked slot. I got stucked here:
I have a QList switch_class named switch_List and I want to do something like that: in the Save Settings():

```
   QSettings setting("myorganization","blabla");
   setting.setValue("list_of_switch_objects",switch_List);//cannot convert from 
   // QList<switch_list> to const QVariant .
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated !

Comment: what is `switch_class`?

Comment: Your question is deficient until you show what `switch_class` is.

Comment: @eyllanesc  switch_class is the name of the class implemented for storing the data of switches. Its a simple class with two constructors, one private qstring method which returns the switch's name, one static variable which contains the no_of_ports, and a qstringlist which stores the pc's mac adresses. nothing suspicious there :D

Comment: @KubaOber hope u see the answer too

Comment: @RaduMarius I do not say it for that, so that you understand me check the comment of KubaOber, if your class can be used in a QDataStream you should not have problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc. I think i cant. Nevermind. Help me with that and im glad, please. I have a QListview and i want to store all the text into a QStringList. I've seen on stack something like:     QStringList list;
    foreach(const QModelIndex &index, ui->QListview->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes())
        list.append(model->itemFromIndex(index)->text()); And they didn't say something about what that "model" is . It's a Qstandardmodel item object? and how can i "connect" him to my qlistview? thank you !

Comment: @RaduMarius mmm, that's another question, do not be distracted please. Are you interested in our help in your current question?

Comment: I know, but i've never worked with QDataStream,there's nothing on youtube and i dont have only QStrings in my switch_class so i dont want to waste your time and me getting upset because of that problem which its too hard for me to solve. So i want to take it easy and at least solve the problem with the QListView

Comment: @eyllanesc so, if u could answer on the QListView i would be grateful.

Comment: @RaduMarius the answer depends on the model, what model are you using ?, in general you should use: `QStringList l; for(int i = 0; i < model->rowCount (); i++) {QModelIndex ix = model->index(i, 0); l << model->data(index).toString();}`

Comment: It worked, thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QSettings::setValue()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#setValue) need a [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) argument. So you have to convert your `QList` into a `QVariant` or a `QVariantList`.

See [this thread's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9265972/1887976) accepted answer for a possible solution:

```
template <typename T>
QVariantList toVariantList( const QList<T> &list )
{
    QVariantList newList;
    foreach( const T &item, list )
        newList << item;

    return newList;
}
```

Alternatively, you can find [some interesting code on Qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#value) that may help you to perform the convertion:

```
QList<int> intList = {7, 11, 42};

QVariant variant = QVariant::fromValue(intList);
if (variant.canConvert<QVariantList>()) {
    QSequentialIterable iterable = variant.value<QSequentialIterable>();
    // Can use foreach:
    foreach (const QVariant &v, iterable) {
        qDebug() << v;
    }
    // Can use C++11 range-for:
    for (const QVariant &v : iterable) {
        qDebug() << v;
    }
    // Can use iterators:
    QSequentialIterable::const_iterator it = iterable.begin();
    const QSequentialIterable::const_iterator end = iterable.end();
    for ( ; it != end; ++it) {
        qDebug() << *it;
    }
}
```

Comment: `QVariant` handles containers automagically, so all that needs to be done is to implement the `QDataStream` operators for `switch_class`, register them, and then `QVariant` will know how to handle that type - whether in containers or not.